# Traversing a linked list with 2 pointer variables in python

Tags: python, linked-list

Say you have a function that sets each `next` value on a node in a linked list to the node that is `val` nodes ahead of it. So if the linked list were to go `2->1->4->2` the resulting linked list would be `2->4` because 4 nodes ahead is out of bounds.

```
    def solve(self, node):
        head = node
        curr = head
        while curr:
            save = curr
            c = 0
            while c < save.val and curr:
                curr = curr.next
                c = c + 1
            save.next = curr
        return head
```

I have this function and it passes all the test cases. But i'm confused on how the head value is updated throughout the function.

Head starts with a copied node from the argument at the start of the function and then is copied into the curr variable. Isn't python all pass by value? Why wouldn't the original passed in node be the value that is also being returned?

Comment: There are no copies being made at all in your code anywhere. And Python is neither call by value nor call by reference

Comment: I suggest you read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Will do, thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Head starts with a copied node

This is the cause of the confusion: the node is not copied. The object's identity is assigned to `head`, which you may imagine as a reference.

Here is a visualisation of what happens in your example code:

It starts with this situation:

```
 node
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val: 2    │    │ val:   1  │    │ val:   4  │    │ val:   2  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

After the first two assignments `head = node` and `curr = head`, and the assignment in the first iteration of the outer loop (`save = curr` ), we have:

```
 node
 head
 save
 curr
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val: 2    │    │ val:   1  │    │ val:   4  │    │ val:   2  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> None
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

After the inner loop has iterated until `c == 2`, we have:

```
 node
 head
 save                              curr
  ↓                                 ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val: 2    │    │ val:   1  │    │ val:   4  │    │ val:   2  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> None
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Then `save.next = curr` is executed, which is the only statement where the list is *mutated*:

```
 node
 head
 save                              curr
  ↓           ┌────────────────┐    ↓
┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val: 2    │ │  │ val:   1  │ └> │ val:   4  │    │ val:   2  │
│ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> None
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

In the next iteration of the outer loop, `save = curr` is executed again:

```
 node                              save
 head                              curr
  ↓           ┌────────────────┐    ↓
┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val: 2    │ │  │ val:   1  │ └> │ val:   4  │    │ val:   2  │
│ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> None
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

And once the inner loop has completed, `curr` will have become `None`:

```
 node                               
 head                              save                             curr
  ↓           ┌────────────────┐    ↓                                ↓
┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val: 2    │ │  │ val:   1  │ └> │ val:   4  │    │ val:   2  │
│ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> None
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Then `save.next = curr` is executed again:

```
 node                               
 head                              save                             curr
  ↓           ┌────────────────┐    ↓           ┌────────────────┐   ↓
┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │
│ val: 2    │ │  │ val:   1  │ └> │ val:   4  │ │  │ val:   2  │ └>
│ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> │ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> None
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Finally we execute `return head`. This returns the exact same reference as was passed to the function as argument (`node`).

NB: because two nodes now have become unreachable, the garbage collector may free their memory, so the caller will end up with this state:

```
 head                              
  ↓                                 
┌───────────┐                     ┌───────────┐
│ val: 2    │                     │ val:   4  │
│ next: ────────────────────────> │ next: ────────────────────────> None
└───────────┘                     └───────────┘
```

Comment: +1 for the effort you put into illustrating this. One piece of advice, you start off by saying "the node is not copied. The reference is copied." and that is *true* for CPython, given that underneath the hood there is some PyObject pointer that is copied into another namespace (be it a dict or a local nampspace array), but I think conceptually that is the wrong level of abstraction. In *python*, nothing is being copied, an object is being assigned to a name.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @juanpa.arrivillaga. I have updated the first paragraph to mention the identity (integer) that uniquely identifies the object.

Comment: thank you @trincot, i understand what's going on!